# Got undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass from pg_search_scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pg-search

I have this pg search scoped

```
pg_search_scope :search_for_result,
  associated_against: {
    organisation: [:name],
    classifications: [:name_fr, :name_en],
    org_classifications: [:name_fr, :name_en],
    entity: [:name_fr, :name_en],
    geocoding: :address_components
  },
  using: { tsearch: { prefix: true } },
  ignoring: :accents
```

This search was working pretty well, before I changed the way my organisation relation was defined in my 'resource' model.

Before I was using an has_one through relationship to describe organisation.

But now I need to have my organisation defined directly in my 'resource' model, so I add an organisation_id field in it. Now the relation of the resource model are defined as follow:

```
belongs_to :organisation
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :entity
has_one :geocoding, dependent: :destroy
has_many :classifications_resources, dependent: :destroy
has_many :org_classifications, through: :user
```

Since I have done this change pg_search_scope is not working anymore and give me the following error:

undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass

here is the full stack:

```
activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/reflection.rb:671:in `source_reflection'
activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/reflection.rb:883:in `derive_class_name'
activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/reflection.rb:157:in `class_name'
activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/reflection.rb:883:in `derive_class_name'
activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/reflection.rb:157:in `class_name'
activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/reflection.rb:650:in `klass'
activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/reflection.rb:135:in `table_name'
pg_search (1.0.6) lib/pg_search/configuration/association.rb:17:in `table_name'
pg_search (1.0.6) lib/pg_search/configuration/association.rb:25:in `subselect_alias'
pg_search (1.0.6) lib/pg_search/configuration/foreign_column.rb:20:in `expression'
pg_search (1.0.6) lib/pg_search/configuration/column.rb:21:in `to_sql'
pg_search (1.0.6) lib/pg_search/features/tsearch.rb:162:in `column_to_tsvector'
pg_search (1.0.6) lib/pg_search/features/tsearch.rb:110:in `block in tsdocument'
pg_search (1.0.6) lib/pg_search/features/tsearch.rb:109:in `map'
pg_search (1.0.6) lib/pg_search/features/tsearch.rb:109:in `tsdocument'
pg_search (1.0.6) lib/pg_search/features/tsearch.rb:140:in `tsearch_rank'
pg_search (1.0.6) lib/pg_search/features/tsearch.rb:24:in `rank'
pg_search (1.0.6) lib/pg_search/scope_options.rb:165:in `block in rank'
pg_search (1.0.6) lib/pg_search/scope_options.rb:164:in `gsub'
pg_search (1.0.6) lib/pg_search/scope_options.rb:164:in `rank'
pg_search (1.0.6) lib/pg_search/scope_options.rb:101:in `subquery'
pg_search (1.0.6) lib/pg_search/scope_options.rb:170:in `rank_join'
pg_search (1.0.6) lib/pg_search/scope_options.rb:20:in `apply'
pg_search (1.0.6) lib/pg_search.rb:39:in `block in pg_search_scope'
lib/modules/search_engine.rb:17:in `find'
```

I really don't know what to do with this.

Is somebody know how I could get more information about what is wrong?

Or is somebody have any idea about what I have done wrong?

Thanks for you comment

Answer (score 0):

Finally found that the error was caused by an other relation... sorry folks